# FPDF en servidor muestra pantalla con errror

Tags: servidor, fpdf

En local me funciona bien, pero al subir mis archivos al servidor (hostinger), cuando llega el momento de pulsar el botón que he creado para esto y que me redirige al archivo "reporte.php" para hacer esta función, me muestra la pantalla en blanco.

Aquí os dejo el código de la pagina "reporte.php":

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Cabecera de página
function Header()
{
    $this->Image('logo_redondo.png',10,5,20);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
    // Movernos a la derecha
    $this->Cell(70);
    // Título
    $this->Cell(60,10,'Cuotas Socios ArtxArt',1,0,'C');
    // Salto de línea
    $this->Ln(20);

    $this->Cell(50, 10, 'NOMBRE', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $this->Cell(60, 10, 'APELLIDO', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $this->Cell(25, 10, 'CUOTA 2018', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $this->Cell(25, 10, 'CUOTA 2019', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $this->Cell(25, 10, 'CUOTA 2020', 1, 1, 'C', 0);
}

    // Pie de página
function Footer()
{
    //Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Número de página
    $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Página ').$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

require 'cnreporte.php';
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM asociados";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);




$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf-> AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);

while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    $pdf->Cell(50, 10, utf8_decode($row['nombre']), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(60, 10, utf8_decode($row['apellido']), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 10, $row['cuota18'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 10, $row['cuota19'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 10, $row['cuota20'], 1, 1, 'C', 0);
}


$pdf->Output('I');
?>
```

Este es el archivo de conexión "cnreporte.php":

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("10.2.1.127:3306", "USUARIO", "CONTRASEÑA", "BASE DE DATOS");
```

Y todo esto viene de una página donde muestro unas tablas (hay que entrar mediante inicio de sesión con usuario y contraseña), que no sé si os haría falta el código, pero que os lo dejo a continuación:
"admin.php"

```
<?php
session_start(); //poner aqui esto solo cuando funcione bien. error_reporting(0);
$varsesion = $_SESSION['usuario'];
$inactivo=600;

if ($varsesion ==null || $varsesion = '') {
    echo 'Usted no tiene autorización';
    die();
}
?>

<?php include("cn.php");
      $nombre = $_SESSION['usuario'];
      $users = "SELECT * FROM asociados WHERE mail='$nombre'";
if (isset($_SESSION["timeout"])) {
    $tiempoSession=time()-$_SESSION["timeout"];
    if($tiempoSession>$inactivo){
        session_destroy();
        header("Location:/login.html");
    }
}

?>

<?php
include("cn.php");
$usuarios = "SELECT * FROM asociados";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ArtxArt</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/asociados.css">     
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/registrar.css">

</head>
    <body>
  <header class="main-header2">
    <div class="container container--flex">
        <div class="logo-negro column">
            <img src="img/tituloheadernegro.png">
        </div>
        <div class="logo-blanco column">
            <img src="img/tituloheader.png">
        </div>

    </div>
  </header>  
  <section class="main-nav2">
       <div class="container container--flex">
           <ul class="menunavegador">
               <?php $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $users);
               while($row=mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {?>  
               <li class="menu__link2">¡ Hola, <?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?> ! </li>
               <?php } ?> 
           </ul>

      <div class="cerrar_sesion">
               <a href="cerrar_session.php">Cerrar sesión</a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </section>


   <main class="main containermain">

<section class="asociados group today-special">
        <div class="container container--flex">

         <div class="container-add">
       <h2 class="container__title">Registrar Nuevo Socio</h2>
       <form action="insertar.php" method="post" class="container__form">
           <label for="" class="container__label">Nombre:</label>
           <input name="nombre" type="text" class="container__input">
           <label for="" class="container__label">Apellido1:</label>
           <input name="apellido" type="text" class="container__input">
           <label for="" class="container__label">Apellido2:</label>
           <input name="apellido2" type="text" class="container__input">
           <label for="" class="container__label">DNI:</label>
           <input name="dni" type="text" class="container__input">
           <label for="" class="container__label">Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
           <input name="fechanacimiento" type="date" class="container__input">
           <label for="" class="container__label">Mail:</label>
           <input name="mail" type="text" class="container__input">
           <label for="" class="container__label">Teléfono:</label>
           <input name="telefono" type="text" class="container__input">
           <label for="" class="container__label">2018:</label>
           <input name="cuota18" type="text" class="container__input">
           <label for="" class="container__label">2019:</label>
           <input name="cuota19" type="text" class="container__input">
           <label for="" class="container__label">2020:</label>
           <input name="cuota20" type="text" class="container__input">
           <input class="container__submit" type="submit" value="Registrar">
       </form>
   </div>

    <div class="container-table">
        <div class="table__title">Cuotas de socios pagadas <a href="edicion.php" class="title_edit">Edición</a></div>
        <div class="table__header">Nombre</div>
        <div class="table__header">Apellidos</div>
        <div class="table__header">Cuota 2018</div>
        <div class="table__header">Cuota 2019</div>
        <div class="table__header">Cuota 2020</div>
        <?php $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $usuarios);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ ?>
        <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["nombre"];?></div>
        <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["apellido"]," ",  $row["apellido2"];?></div>
        <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["cuota18"];?></div>
        <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["cuota19"];?></div>
        <div class="table__item"><?php echo $row["cuota20"];?></div>
        <?php } mysqli_free_result($resultado);?>

    </div>  



    </div>

    <div class="volver3">
        <a href="reporte.php" target="_blank"><h2>Generar Reporte</h2></a>
        </div>

       </section>
</main>

<footer class="main-footer">
           <div class="container container--flex">
               <div class="column">
                  <p class="copy">
                 <a href="aviso%20legal.pdf" target="_blank">Aviso Legal</a> 
                 <a href="Pol%C3%ADtica%20de%20privacidad%20-%20ARTxART.pdf" target="_blank">Política de privacidad</a>  
                 <a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></p>
               </div>

               <div class="column_footer">
               <a href="https://www.facebook.com/artxart.cultura"><img src="img/facebookgris.png" class="iconos_facebook"></a>
               <a href="https://www.instagram.com/artxart_cultura"><img src="img/instagramgris.png" class="iconos_instagram"></a>
               <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvpZER9-Okmamo2fxsLH0qg"><img src="img/youtubegris.png" class="iconos_youtube"></a>
           </div>

              <div class="column"> 
               <p class="copy2">© 2013 &nbsp; ArtxArt - Cultura en Acció &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;Todos los derechos reservados</p>
           </div>
           </div>
       </footer>
        <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
        <script src="js/menu2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/menu3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/menu4.js"></script>
        <script src="js/menu5.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: buenas, tu codigo esta bien confuso, veo que tienes 2 archivos de conexion. Dejalos siempre al inicio del php -> <?php

  
  session_start();
   require 'cn.php';
  require 'cnreporte.php';

Comment: Hola! Si, uno esta en diferente archivo, ya que se usa para iniciar sesion de usuario y verifica al usuario.  Para "reporte.php" usé uno direfente porque  lo hice para local, con una base de datos que tenia en local, y luego cambiando la conexion esa, lo use en remoto. He conseguido, cambiando en la parte del final del "reporte" donde dice $pdf=new PDF(), si pongo new FPDF, me muestra la tabla, pero ni el header ni el footer.... Si no lo cambio, la pagina simplemente se muestra blanca. (ya no sale el mensaje de ERROR)

Comment: Puse el codigo del final, porque es desde la pagina donde llamo a "reporte.php", pero no creo que sea relevante. El fallo estará en algo del código de "reporte.php" que funciona en local, pero no funciona en el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCIONADO!

Resulta que en el Header, la imagen que hay puesta tiene como extenxión .PNG y yo tenía puesto .png, y es sensible a las mayúsculas. Al fallar eso, por lo visto bloqueaba toda el resto del código.
Es raro, porque una de mis opciones de corrección fue eliminar la imagen, pero seguramente lo haría junto a alguna otra corrección más y la casualidad sería que seguiría mal la otra corrección. Pero cambiando a mayúsculas eso, se ha resuelto.
Muchas gracias a todos y espero le sirva a alguien si le pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Es cierto. El tema que la funcion Image(..) tiene como parametro el tipo de imagen a publicar. Los valores posibles con JPG, JPEG, PNG y GIF... si TODOS EN MAYUSCULA.  Si no lo especificas, toma el tipo de imagen del Type de la imagen. Presumo que si la extensión va en minúscula no lo encuentra y da error. Yo estuve 2 días detrás de esto, hasta que di con tu consulta y al cambiar la extensión a PNG se solucionó. Supuestamente en la clase, previo a considerar en Type lo deja en minúscula. Pero parece no funcionar bien